# Assign a list of values to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose there is a 2-dimensional `numpy` array of shape `(10000, 100)` and size `1000000`. There is also a 1-dimensional `list` of length `1000000`. What would be the fastest way to assign all the values in the list to the array? My solution is:

```
my_array = np.zeros([10000, 100]) 
my_list = range(1000000)
length_of_list = len(my_list)

for i in range(length_of_list):                  
    my_array.flat[i] = my_list[i]
```

Is there maybe a better one?

Comment: `my_array.flat[:] = my_list` is possible. It avoids the for loop, But turns out to run at the same speed.

Answer (score 3):

I thought that turning the list to an array and reshaping it then would be the fastest solution, but it turned out in my setup @M4rtini's one-liner is even faster:

```
In [25]: %%timeit -n 10 
   ....: for i in range(length_of_list):                  
   ....:     my_array.flat[i] = my_list[i]
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 420 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit -n 10 my_array.flat[:] = my_list
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit -n 10 my_array = np.array(my_list).reshape(10000, 100)
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop
```

Comment: seems like i messed up my timings :) forgot to convert the range object to a list first, still getting used to py3